# Negate wildcard on Openbox rc.xml

Tags: lubuntu, openbox

I'm trying to configure my Openbox to open every window but `dialog` type maximized.

```
  <applications>
    <application type="!(dialog)"> <!-- here -->
      <maximized>true</maximized>
      ...
  </applications>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to negate a pattern on Openbox. Neither `!(dialog)` nor `[^dialog]*` worked. I'm sure I can achieve this on Openbox, but how to make this match all types but `dialog`?

Answer (score 1):

This solved what I was trying to do.

```
<applications>
        <application name="*">
          <maximized>true</maximized>
        </application>

        <application type="dialog">
          <maximized>false</maximized>
        </application>
</applications>
```

Comment: You could include the basis for your solution: "For instance you could write one rule to match against all windows and then later rules could further change things for more specific windows. The rules are matched in the order they appear in your configuration file, so later rules will override previous rules if they both specify the same setting for a window." from the section titled "Matching against multiple rules" in http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Applications